# send text message from java server to android client usig sockets by clicking on a button

Tags: java, android, sockets

I need to send a text message from core java server to android client by clicking on a button.  However, it does not show an error, and the  message is not sent to client side.

**Server side button code:**

```
private void msg_sendActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)   {                                         
// TODO add your handling code here:
    String msgout="";
    msgout=msg_text.getText().toString();
    try{
        dout.writeUTF(msgout);
        //printWriter.write(msgout + "\n");
        System.out.printf(msgout);
        //printWriter.flush();
    }catch(Exception e){

    }
}
```

**Client side code:**

```
Thread r = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            s = new Socket("192.168.1.5", 1201);
            // din=new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());
            inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream());
            bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);

            dataout = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
            String message = "";
            while (!message.equals("exit")) {
                //msgin=din.readUTF();
                message = bufferedReader.readLine();

                msg_area.setText(msg_area.getText().toString() + "\n       Server:\t" + message);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Exception-->" + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    }
});
r.start();
```

Comment: So in the server you click on a button? What kind of server has buttons?

Comment: If the the client tries to read a line with .readLine() the server should have send a line. But your server does not. Instead it sends an UTFstring.

Comment: `msg_area.setText()`. You cannot set a text in a textview in the run of a thread.

Comment: `Toast.makeText()`. You cannot display a toast in the run() of a thread.

Comment: the server is a java server on netbeans (if I understand ur question )

Comment: i tried also readUTF but the same thing happens

Answer (score 0):

`readLine()` reads lines. You aren't sending a line. You're sending with `writeUTF()`, which uses a special format, documented in the Javadoc. Either send lines or use `readUTF)`.

Comment: i tried both of them actually ... I think  that the reading thread cant work with the ui thread